# Need to make my code faster. Storing results of repeating statements in array of Boolean

Tags: delphi, optimization

My project deals with historical and real time data analysis. Contains several complex algorithms (over 800) at its last stage. Overall the analysis stages are roughly as follows:

1. Basic formulas calculation->results storage
2. Second stage formulas using above formulas->results storage
3. Third stage formulas which decide upon desired action.

These third stage formulas are large blocks of complex conditionals. These complex conditionals though, use a finite number of simpler statements. And as a result these simpler statements get repeated a lot of times among the complex conditionals. Let me give you a greatly simplified example.

```
if ((var1[0]<var2[0]*0.5)and(var3[0]=1))or(var15[1]<>var15[0]))
....lots of similar statements....
then take action.
```

Now, Statements like

```
"(var3[0]=1)" or "(var15[1]<>var15[0])"
```

get used over and over again in other if blocks. My idea is to parse all these unique simple statements and automatically create some code that calculates their result (true/false) and stores them in an array of Boolean, once before Third stage commences. Like so:

```
arr[12]:=var1[0]<var2[0]*0.5;
arr[13]:=var3[0]=1;
...
arr[128]:=var15[1]<>var15[0];
```

Then (again by parsing my code before compiling) substitute the simpler statements with their corresponding array elements.
So, instead of

```
if ((var1[0]<var2[0]*0.5)and(var3[0]=1))or(var15[1]<>var15[0]))
```

it would look like

```
if ((arr[12])and(arr[13]))or(arr[128])
```

Would these changes in my code speed up my execution(calculation) time? Or the compiler already does something similar and I will just be wasting my time? Keep in mind that these simple statements get repeated tens or hundreds of times during each calculation cycle. And there is a minimum of 300,000 cycles to be calculated before real time data kick in. So, every little helps. In essence I am asking if a comparison between variables is slower than the retrieval of a Boolean array element's value;

**UPDATE**

Since some people asked for some real code, here is one part of real code. 98% of code is variables (everything with [0] is a variable allowing access to previous variable values). 2% is functions. Variables are calculated in previous stage. Almost all variables are integers. There are over 800 similar blocks overall. Minimum 300,000 cycles of calculation. Average time is about 45 seconds. For reasons I don't need to explain here, I should make it 2x faster. Code could be in different form if the people writing the algorithms were programmers. But they aren't. They can handle up to some basic stuff like conditional blocks. This is something that can't be changed.

I noticed some people coming here with intend to express irony. Please stay away. I need not your help. People who are willing to offer a constructive opinion are more than welcome to do so. In fact I thank them in advance for just making the effort to read such a long post. I am sorry for the bad code formatting, It was a failed effort to post it as code here.

```
if   ( ZEChT01Pc[0] < ZEChT02Pc[0])
and( ZEChP01Pc[0] < ZEChP02Pc[0])
and( ZEChT01Bn[0] > ZEChP01Bn[0])
and( BncUp_TL_P_1_2[0] > ZEChT01Bn[0])
and( higSncZEChT01[0] < HZigCh30[0])
and( ((ZEChT01Pc[0] < LZigCh30[0]) )
     or
       ( (ZEChT01Pc[0] < LZigCh3002[0] )    and( LZigCh30[0] < LZigCh3002[0] )    and( ZEChT01Pc[0] <= Bnc_Up_HZigCh_Pr[0]) )
       or
       ( (ZEChT01Pc[0] < LZigCh3002[0] )    and( LZigCh30[0] < LZigCh3002[0] )    and( ZEChT01Pc[0] > Bnc_Up_HZigCh_Pr[0] )    and( ZEChP02Pc[0] < TFZ11EndPc[0])) )
and( ((TL_Pks_1_2.tl_getvalue(0) < LZigCh30[0] + ((HZigCh30[0] - LZigCh30[0] )*0.80)) )
     or
       ( (ZEChT01Pc[0] < ULX2dly[0] )    and( C[0] > DLX2dly[0])) )
and (( (ZECoP01Bn[0] > ZEChP01Bn[0])    and (ZECoP01Bn[0] < ZEChT01Bn[0])
and (( (ZECoP01Pc[0] <= ZECoP02Pc[0])    and (C[0] > TL_ECo_Trs_1_2.tl_getvalue(0) )) or ( (ZECoP01Pc[0] > ZECoP02Pc[0]) )) )
     or
   ( (ZECoP01Bn[0] = ZEChP01Bn[0])    and (ZECoP02Bn[0] < ZEChT02Bn[0])  ))
and (( (C[0] > ULX30[0])    and (C[1] <= ULX30[0])    and (ULX30[0] > TL_Pks_1_2.tl_getValue(0))
and (( (BrUpULX30[1] < ZEchT01Bn[0]) ) or ( (chgZigLCh[0] > BrUpULX30[1]) )) )
     or
     ( (C[0] > TL_Pks_1_2.tl_getvalue(0))    and (C[1] <= TL_Pks_1_2.tl_getvalue(0))    and ( TL_Pks_1_2.tl_getValue(0) > ULX30[0])    and (BncUp_TL_P_1_2[1] < ZEchT01Bn[0]) ))
and( ((uniBrUpULX3002_bn[0] > ZEChT01Bn[0] )    and( uniBrUpULX30[0] > TL_Pks_1_2.tl_getvalue(0) )    and( uniBrUpULX3002[0] < TL_Pks_1_2.tl_getvalue(0)) )= false)
and( ((uniBrUpULX3002_bn[0] > ZEChT01Bn[0] )    and( uniBrUpULX30[0] > TL_Pks_1_2.tl_getvalue(0) )    and( uniBrUpULX3002[0] > TL_Pks_1_2.tl_getvalue(0)) )= false)
and( NoLong[0] = 0)
and( ((TL_Pks_1_2.tl_getvalue(0) < LZigCh30[0] )    and( chgZigLCh[0] < ZEChT01Bn[0] )    and( ULX30[0] > LZigCh30[0]) )= false)
and( ((((C[0] < DLXdly[0] )    and( HZigCh30[0] < DLXdly[0] - Tk(0.0050)) = false)))
      or
      ( (ZEChT01Bn[0] = TFZ10EndBnum[0] )    and( ZEChT01Pc[0] < TFZ20EndPc[0] )    and( higSncZEChT01[0] > TFZ40EndPc[0])) )
and( ((ZEChP01Pc[0] > DLXdly[0] )    and( ZEChT01Pc[0] < DLXdly[0] )    and( HZigCh30[0] < DLXdly[0] )) = false)
and( ((higSncZEChT01[0] > HZigCh30[0] -Tk(0.0010) )    and( Bnc_Dn_HZigCh[0]  > higbarSncZEChT01[0]) )= false)
and( ((TFZ10EndBnum[0] > TFZ11EndBnum[0] )    and( TFZ10Type[0]= 5 )    and( TFZ10Extension[0] = 0 )    and( ULX30[0] < LZigCh30[0]) )= false)
and( ((Bnc_Dn_LZigCh[0] > ZEChT01Bn[0] )    and( C[0] < LZigCh30[0]) )= false)
and( ((ZEChP01Pc[0] > DLXdly[0] )    and( ZEChT01Pc[0] < DLXdly[0] )    and( C[0] < DLXdly[0] )    and( First[0] = -1) )= false)
and( ((LZigCh3002[0] >  DLXdly[0] )    and( LZigCh30[0] <  DLXdly[0] )    and( C[0] < DLXdly[0])    and( HZigCh3002[0] >  DLXdly[0] )    and( HZigCh30[0] <  DLXdly[0] )) = false)
and( ((LZigCh3003[0] >  DLXdly[0] )    and( LZigCh3002[0] <  DLXdly[0] )    and( C[0] < DLXdly[0])
and( HZigCh3002[0] >  DLXdly[0] )    and( HZigCh30[0] <  DLXdly[0] )    and( LZigCh30[0] < DLXdly[0] )    and( currentbar - chgZigLCh[0] <= 3 )) = false)
and( ((((TFZ10EndBnum[0] > TFZ11EndBnum[0] )    and( C[0] > higSncShFrm[0]  - ((higSncShFrm[0] - TFZ10EndPc[0])*0.5) )    and( higBarSncShFrm[0] <= ZEChP02Bn[0]) = false)))
     or
     ( (ZEChT01Pc[0] < DLXdly[0] )    and( C[0] > DLXdly[0])) )
and( ((C[0] <= LZigCh30[0] )    and( H[0] > LZigCh30[0]) = false))
and( ((ZEChT01Pc[0] < ULXdly[0] )    and( ZEChT02Pc[0] < ULXdly[0] )    and( ZEChP01Pc[0] > ULXdly[0] )
and( ZEChP02Pc[0] > ULXdly[0] )    and( ZEChT01Pc[0] < ZEChT02Pc[0])    and  (BncUpDLXdly[0] < ZEchT01Bn[0]) )= false)
and( ((((TFZ11EndBnum[0] > TFZ10EndBnum[0] )    and( ZEChT01Pc[0] > TFZ11EndPc[0] - ((TFZ11EndPc[0] - TFZ10EndPc[0])*0.382)) = false)))
      or
      ( (C[0] > ULXdly[0])) )
and( ((((TFZ10EndBnum[0] > TFZ11EndBnum[0] )    and( TFZ20EndBnum[0] < TFZ11EndBnum[0] )    and( ZEChT01Pc[0] > TFZ11EndPc[0] - ((TFZ11EndPc[0] - TFZ20EndPc[0])*0.382)) )= false))
      or
      ( (C[0] > ULXdly[0])) )
and( ((((TFZ20EndBnum[0] > TFZ11EndBnum[0] )    and( TFZ30EndBnum[0] < TFZ11EndBnum[0] )    and( ZEChT01Pc[0] > TFZ11EndPc[0] - ((TFZ11EndPc[0] - TFZ30EndPc[0])*0.382)) )= false))
      or
      ( (C[0] > ULXdly[0])))
and( ((((TFZ30EndBnum[0] > TFZ11EndBnum[0] )    and( TFZ40EndBnum[0] < TFZ11EndBnum[0] )    and( ZEChT01Pc[0] > TFZ11EndPc[0] - ((TFZ11EndPc[0] - TFZ40EndPc[0])*0.382)) )= false))
      or
      ( (C[0] > ULXdly[0])))
and( ((ZEChP01Pc[0] > ZEChP03Pc[0] )    and( ZEChP01Pc[0] > ZEChP04Pc[0]  )    and( C[0] < DLXdly[0]) = false) )
and (( (( (LZigCh30[0] < DLXdly[0] )    and( LZigCh3002[0] > DLXdly[0] )    and( ZEChP01Pc[0] < DLXdly[0] )    and( C[0] < DLXdly[0]) ) = false))
      or
      ( (ZEchT01Pc[0] = TFZ10EndPc[0]) or (ZEchT02Pc[0] = TFZ20EndPc[0]) or (ZEchT03Pc[0] = TFZ30EndPc[0]) ))
and( NoLong2[0] = 0 )
and( ((ZEChP02Pc[0] > ULX2dly[0] )    and( ZEChP01Pc[0] < ULXdly[0] )    and( C[0] < ULX2dly[0] )    and( BrDnDLXdly[0] < BrUpULXdly[0])
and( Min(ZEChT01Pc[0],ZEChT02Pc[0]) > ULXdly[0] - ((ULXdly[0] - DLXdly[0]) * 0.618)) )= false)
and( ((BrDnDLXdly[0] < BrUpULXdly[0] )    and( Min(ZEChT01Pc[0],ZEChT02Pc[0]) > ULXdly[0] - ((ULXdly[0] - DLXdly[0]) * 0.4))
and( TFZ10EndBnum[0] > TFZ11EndBnum[0] )    and( C[0] < ULX2dly[0] )    and( ULXdly[0] > ULX2dly[0] ) )= false)
and( ((BrDnDLXdly[0] < BrUpULXdly[0] )    and( TFZ10EndPc[0]  > ULXdly[0] - ((ULXdly[0] - DLXdly[0]) * 0.4))
and( TFZ10EndBnum[0] < TFZ11EndBnum[0] )    and( C[0] < ULX2dly[0] )    and( ULXdly[0] > ULX2dly[0] ) )= false)
and( ((ZEChP02Pc[0] > ULX2dly[0] )    and( ZEChP01Pc[0] < ULXdly[0] )    and( C[0] < ULX2dly[0] )    and( BrDnDLXdly[0] < BrUpULXdly[0])
and( C[0] > LZigCh30[0] + ((HZigCh30[0] - LZigCh30[0]) * 0.768) )    and( C[0] < ULX2dly[0]) )= false)
and( ((LZigCh30[0] < DLXdly[0] )    and( DLXdly[0] < HZigCh30[0] )    and( C[0] > LZigCh30[0] + ((DLXdly[0] - LZigCh30[0])*0.618))
and( DLXdly[0] - C[0]  < Tk(0.0040) )    and( C[0] < DLXdly[0] ) )= false)
and( ((((ZEChT01Bn[0] <> TFZ10EndBnum[0] )    and( ZEChT01Pc[0] >= LZigCh30[0])) = false))
      or
      ( (ZEChT01Pc[0] < LZigCh30[0] )    and( C[0] > LZigCh30[0] )    and( LZigCh30[0] > ULXdly[0]))
      or
      ( (LZigCh30[0] < LZigCh3002[0] )    and( chgZigLCh[0] > ZEChT01Bn[0] )    and( ZEChP01Pc[0] < LZigCh3002[0] )    and( C[0] > ZEChT02Pc[0] ) )
      or
      ( (ZEChT01Pc[0] <= DLXdly[0] )    and( C[0] > DLXdly[0])))
and( ((C[0] < TFZ20EndPc[0] )    and( C[0] < LZigCh3002[0] )    and( TFZ20Type[0] > 3 )    and( ((TFZ20EndBnum[0] = ZEChT02Bn[0]) )or( (TFZ20EndBnum[0] = ZEChT03Bn[0]))) )= false)
and( ((((ZEChT01Bn[0] <> TFZ10EndBnum[0] )    and( ZEChT01Pc[0] < LZigCh30[0] )    and( LZigCh30[0] > ULXdly[0]) )= false))
      or
      ( (C[0] < LZigCh30[0] + ((HZigCh30[0] - LZigCh30[0] )*0.618) )    and( HZigCh30[0] - C[0] >= Tk(0.0040)) ))
and( ((LZigCh30[0] < DLXdly[0] )    and( LZigCh3002[0] > DLXdly[0] )    and( ZEChP02Pc[0] < DLXdly[0] + Tk(0.0050) )
and( ZEChP02Pc[0] < LZigCh3002[0] )    and( C[0] < LZigCh3002[0] ) = false))
and ( (( (HZigCh30[0] < DLXdly[0])    and (HZigCh3002[0] > DLXdly[0])    and (ZEchT01Bn[0] = TFZ10EndBnum[0])
and (TFZ10Type[0] = 5 )    and (TFZ10Extension[0] = 0)    and (DLXdly[0] < DLX2dly[0]) ) = false) )
and (( (( (chgULXdly[0] > ZEchP01Bn[0])    and (ULXdly[0] > ULX2dly[0])    and (C[0] < ULXdly[0])    and (ZEchT01Pc[0] > ULX2dly[0]) )=false))
      or
      ( (TFZ10EndBnum[0] = ZEchT01Bn[0])    and (TFZ10Type[0] > 3) ))
and (( (( (chgULXdly[0] > ZEchP01Bn[0])    and (ULXdly[0] > ULX2dly[0])    and (C[0] < ULXdly[0])    and (C[0] < ULX2dly[0]))= false))
    or
    ( ( ZechT01Pc[0] < ULXdly[0] - ((ULXdly[0] - DLXdly[0])*0.75))    and (C[0] > LZigCh30[0])    and (DLX30[0] > LZigCh30[0]) ))
and (( (( (chgULXdly[0] > ZEchP01Bn[0])    and (ULXdly[0] < ULX2dly[0])    and (C[0] < ULXdly[0]) ) = false))
       or
       ( ( ZechT01Pc[0] < ULXdly[0] - ((ULXdly[0] - DLXdly[0])*0.75))    and (C[0] > LZigCh30[0])    and (DLX30[0] > LZigCh30[0]) ))
and (( (TFZ11EndBnum[0] = ZEchP02Bn[0])    and (TFZ11Type[0] > 3)    and (min(ZEchT01Pc[0],ZechT02Pc[0]) = TFZ10EndPc[0])    and (C[0] < ULXdly[0])
and (TFZ10Type[0] = 3)    and (TFZ10Extension[0] = 2)    and (TFZ10EndPc[0] > ULXdly[0] - ((ULXdly[0] - DLXdly[0])*0.5)) ) = false)
and (( (TFZ11EndBnum[0] = ZEchP02Bn[0])    and (TFZ11Type[0] > 3)    and (min(ZEchT01Pc[0],ZechT02Pc[0]) = TFZ10EndPc[0])    and (C[0] < ULXdly[0])
and (( (TFZ10Type[0] = 3)    and (TFZ10Extension[0] = 2) )= false)    and (TFZ10EndPc[0] > ULXdly[0] - ((ULXdly[0] - DLXdly[0])*0.8)) ) = false)
and (( (( (TFZ11EndBnum[0] = ZEchP02Bn[0])    and (TFZ11Type[0] > 3)    and (min(ZEchT01Pc[0],ZechT02Pc[0]) <> TFZ10EndPc[0])) = false))
     or
     ( (min(ZEchT01Pc[0],ZechT02Pc[0]) < ULXdly[0] - ((ULXdly[0] - DLXdly[0])*0.8)) )
     or
     ( (Bnc_Up_LZigCh[0] > ZEchT01Bn[0])    and (ZEchT01Pc[0] > ZechP03Pc[0]) ))
and (( (ZechT01Pc[0] < ZechT02Pc[0])    and (ZechP01Pc[0] < ZechP02Pc[0])    and (ZEchT01Pc[0] > ULXdly[0])    and (C[0] < ZEchT02Pc[0])    and (C[0] > ULXdly[0]) ) = false)
and (( (ZechT01Pc[0] < ZechT02Pc[0])    and (ZechP01Pc[0] < ZechP02Pc[0])    and (ZEchT01Pc[0] > ULXdly[0])    and (ZEchP02Bn[0] = TFZ11EndBnum[0])
and (ZEchT02Bn[0]= TFZ20EndBnum[0])    and (ZEchT01Bn[0]= TFZ10EndBnum[0])    and (TFZ10Type[0] = 3)    and (C[0] > ULXdly[0]) )= false)
and (( (ZechT01Pc[0] < ZechT02Pc[0])    and (ZechP01Pc[0] < ZechP02Pc[0])    and (ZEchT01Pc[0] > ULXdly[0])    and (ZEchP03Bn[0] = TFZ11EndBnum[0])
and (ZEchT02Bn[0]= TFZ20EndBnum[0])    and (ZEchT01Bn[0]= TFZ10EndBnum[0])    and (TFZ10Type[0] = 3)    and (C[0] > ULXdly[0]) )= false)
and (((( (TFZ10Type[0] = 7)    and (TFZ20type[0] = 5)    and (TFZ10Extension[0] = 0)    and (TFZ20Extension[0] = 0)    and (TFZ10EndPc[0] > ULXdly[0] - ((ULXdly[0] - DLXdly[0])*0.5))) = false))
      or
      ( (C[0] > ULXdly[0]) ) or ( (ZechT01Pc[0] < ULX2dly[0] )    and (C[0] > ULX2dly[0])    and (ULX2dly[0] < ULXdly[0]) ))
and (( (max(HZigCh30[0],HZigCh3002[0]) - LZigCh30[0] < Tk(0.0100))    and (C[0] > LZigCh30[0] + ((max(HZigCh30[0],HZigCh3002[0]) - LZigCh30[0])*0.618)) ) = false)
and (( (ZEchP02Pc[0] > ULXdly[0] - ((ULXdly[0] - DLXdly[0])*0.236))    and (ZEchT01Bn[0] <> TFZ10EndBnum[0])    and (BncUpDLXdly[0] < ZEchT01Bn[0])) = false)
and (( (Bnc_Dn_LZigCh[0] > ZEChT01Bn[0] )    and (C[0] < LZigCh30[0]) ) = false)
and (( (TFZ41EndBnum[0] > TFZ10EndBnum[0])    and (C[0] < ULXdly[0])    and  (BncUpDLXdly[0] < ZEchT01Bn[0]) ) = false)
and ( GenL01[0] = false)
and ( GenL02[0] = false)
and ( GenL03[0] = false)
and ( GenL04[0] = True)
then
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: `var1`, `var3`, `arr`, really? Negative, show us real code (i really hope this is just an example, not real code).

Comment: @ion - before considering optimization, I suggest considering some serious design changes/refactoring. Delphi is a high-level language - take advantage of it. For example - see this link and the comments/answers: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/109138/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-short-circuit-evaluation-instead-of-an-if-clause

Comment: @ion, How long is this code taking, and how much faster would you like it to run?

Comment: @Downvoter, I really hope you are joking about this being real code.

Comment: @Mikey, I can't really make any major design changes. Since I am not the one actually writing the algorithms, I have to maintain a level of simplicity so that the people who write them, can do so with ease (meaning, they choose the names of the variables and they know what they stand for. As well as the meaning of "and" and "or"...)

Comment: @johan - I would be extremely satisfied with 30%-50% faster execution.

Comment: @ion - I gather you mean to say they are not really programmers and you don't have much control over what they do. (everyone in math/science/engineering understand how 'and' 'or' work but stringing them together and nesting them in this manner is something that no good programmer would do. So I guess you just have to make the best of it, as you are trying to do. But I pity others who will have to look at that stuff after the original conceivers leave... good luck.

Comment: @ion, i cannot express which of your attempts to post code was worse. Be happy about what your real code works at all, because you unlikely will be able to fix it if something will happen. This should be rewritten by competent programmer to be maintainable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitely store the results in array as you pointed. Compiler don't know the values you are computing and doesn't store the results in some temporary stack in case of repetitive formulas. That's what are variables for.

So yes, this will speed up your calculation time.
**Update**
Here is the simple example and dissasembly generated by Delphi 2009. As you can see in dissasembly storing results to the variables takes some CPU cycles though but comparing of booleans from the array takes only 4 instructions. So if you save your results once then your comparisions will take only these 4 instructions instead of 14 each time.

You can see the dissasembly by entering the breakpoint at debug mode and showing the Dissasembly window from View/Debug Windows/CPU Windows/Dissasembly.

Please note that this may differ a bit depending on your Delphi version.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Result: Boolean;
  X: array [0..1] of Double;
  Y: array [0..1] of Double;
begin
  X[0] := 0.25;
  X[1] := 0.75;
  Y[0] := 0.25;
  Y[1] := 0.75;

  if (X[0] < X[1] * 0.5) and (Y[0] < Y[1] * 0.5) then
    Result := True;

  if Result then
    ShowMessage('Result = True'); // to prevent optimization
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Result: Boolean;
  X: array [0..1] of Double;
  Y: array [0..1] of Double;
  Z: array [0..1] of Boolean;
begin
  X[0] := 0.25;
  X[1] := 0.75;
  Y[0] := 0.25;
  Y[1] := 0.75;

  Z[0] := (X[0] < X[1] * 0.5);
  Z[1] := (Y[0] < Y[1] * 0.5);

  if Z[0] and Z[1] then
    Result := True;

  if Result then
    ShowMessage('Result = True'); // to prevent optimization
end;
```

And the dissasembly
At Button1Click you can see the direct comparision

```
if (X[0] < X[1] * 0.5) and (Y[0] < Y[1] * 0.5) then
-----------------------------------------------------
fld    qword ptr [esp+$08]
fmul   dword ptr [$0046cdbc]
fcomp  qword ptr [esp]
wait
fstsw  ax
sahf
jbe    $0046cda7
fld    qword ptr [esp+$18]
fmul   dword ptr [$0046cdbc]
fcomp  qword ptr [esp+$10]
wait
fstsw  ax
sahf
jbe    $0046cda7

Result := True;
-----------------------------------------------------
mov    dl,$01
```

At Button2Click storing of the results takes some time but comaprision itself takes only 4 instructions

```
Z[0] := (X[0] < X[1] * 0.5);
-----------------------------------------------------
fld    qword ptr [esp+$10]
fmul   dword ptr [$0046ce78]
fcomp  qword ptr [esp+$08]
wait
fstsw  ax
sahf
setnbe al
mov    [esp],al

Z[1] := (Y[0] < Y[1] * 0.5);
-----------------------------------------------------
fld    qword ptr [esp+$20]
fmul   dword ptr [$0046ce78]
fcomp  qword ptr [esp+$18]
wait
fstsw  ax
sahf
setnbe al
mov    [esp+$01],al

if Z[0] and Z[1] then
-----------------------------------------------------
cmp    byte ptr [esp],$00
jz     $0046ce63
cmp    byte ptr [esp+$01],$00
jz     $0046ce63

Result := True;
-----------------------------------------------------
mov    dl,$01
```

Comment: Your example will result in complete boolean evaluation even if that is not necessary, e.g. even if (X[0] < X[1] * 0.5) is false, it will still evaluate (Y[0] < Y[1] * 0.5).

Answer (score 5):

Your approach sounds deeply flawed from a software development perspective. Code like `if ((arr[12])and(arr[13]))or(arr[128])` is essentially unreadable and unmaintainable.

You should create properties for the commonly used boolean values and give them meaningful names. If you find it hard to name a property then don't be afraid to write

```
if height>CriticalHeight then
```

The performance benefits of caching the results of these tests will be unmeasurable in my experience. Your current approach is sure to result in defects and incorrect code.

Comment: +1. My first though was "Nice, detailed question. Oh, wait... There's absolutely no mention of a profiler. Another case of premature optimization." I see nothing to change that anywhere, and maintenance in either case would be an absolute nightmare (plus now the added maintenance of a code parser, as mentioned in the question and then the poster's comment to az01).

Comment: @David, measurable maybe at 300,000 cycles what OP mentioned. +1 for unreadability.

Comment: "....lots of similar statements...."
I feel faint - please pass the smelling salts..

Comment: "Another case of premature optimization." IMO it's not premature, its irrelevant - this code appears indecipherable and therefore invalid IMO.

Comment: The combinations are too many to make variables for them. And in the end it would make the code even more difficult to read. But to an extend you are correct and this is something that will take place. But up to the extend of the code remaining easy to read to those who write it. They are not programmers. But they can write in a script language.

Comment: If you can't make good names you are not trying hard enough. I would never accept such code in a code review. I'd also have to consider the future of a dev that submitted such code.

Answer (score 1):

In both case you'll have some tests (what you call 'retrieval of Boolean' still recquires a test) but the optimized version will be bit faster. Because you always test a true/false state, the compiler will generate some TEST/SETNZ and much lesser conditional jumps that if you repeat the whole test.

```
if ((arr[12])and(arr[13]))or(arr[128])
```

will generate something like ( without memory operations, pseudo asm code):

```
TEST arr[12] arr[12]
SETNZ bytePtr[esp+4] // local variable
TEST arr[13] arr[13]
SETNZ bytePtr[esp+5]// local variable
TEST arr[128] arr[128]
SETNZ bytePtr[esp+6]// local variable

AND bytePtr[esp+4],bytePtr[esp+5]
OR bytePtr[esp+4],bytePtr[esp+6]

TEST bytePtr[esp+4],bytePtr[esp+4],
JNZ // wrong

...// processing
```

Comment: So, I should try and detect "repeating groups of statements" first, and then detect the rest of non-grouped statements. This seems to me the solution for the least amount of TESTS.

Comment: Yes, of course, my answer is just here to precise that you will always get some tests. It doesn't go in the opposite way of TLama's answer.

Comment: I would correct you a bit. In case of formulas like `var1[0]<var2[0]*0.5` you have to compare floating type of values, so it will generate `fcomp` in your assembly. In case of boolean comparisions it will generate `cmp` in your code. But still comparing of two bits will be faster than computed float comparision.

Comment: I see. I just hope this whole procedure will make some meaningful difference in calculation time. I guess the only way to really find out is to make it and test it. After all it should just be a couple days of extra work for the code Parser and the possibility of better results is certainly worth it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @ion If all you do anything at all other than the if tests then you will not be able to measure the performance difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think your idea of pre-calculating all sub-expressions could work, but that's not the end of it, not by a long shot!

First, you should re-order the expression in such a way that the condition that has the highest (measured) chance of failure is evaluated first. This prevents lots of unnecessary evaluations that will be discarded anyway. (As soon as one of the steps in a big "if X and Y and Z" expression fail, the following steps won't be executed, hence you can take advantage of that fact by evaluating the worst conditions first.)

This could be troublesome to do by hand, so another idea could be, to create a list for all your expressions, and keep count of how often they are evaluated, and how often they fail. (Also, don't forget to reset these counts after some time.) If you (bubble-)sort this list regularly, the evaluations will speed up, as you only evaluate the steps that (currently) have the best chance of failure.

Next, you could try to use on-demand fetching of the variables. Instead of calculating everything up-front, only evaluate the variables that are needed for each part of your expression, by using a callback method. (This may also help for the first stage, as for some expressions, you might only use part of the second stage, which in turn might only need part of the first stage).

Summarizing :

- create a record for each expression, containing a callback, a hit-count and a failure count
- put these records in an array, and sort the array once every 100 iterations or so
- evaluate the expressions top-down, simply by invoking the callback and keeping counts
- each callback could be implemented using "dynamic variables" (which can also be kept in a record, using a callback to get the actual value)

PS: instead of resetting all values, I often use a tick-counter : each variable that doesn't meet the current "tick" needs an update. By remembering the 'tick' at which a variable is calculated, you can see if it's already up-to-date or not, and save on clearing the variables in the same time! (Just increase the tick right before each iteration, and you're set)

Good luck!